# getting the message "out of partition" after installing GRUB 2. What is happening?

Tags: boot, grub2, x86

I recently moved a partition with a complete Linux install except `/home` to a new disk (with DD).

Everything went fine, I can mount the partition, browse it... perfect.

Next step: install GRUB to make it bootable.

Restarted from a Live CD mounted the partition (`mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/root/`)

and installed GRUB:

```
grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/root /dev/sda
```

I get a success message when I do this.

Now, when I boot, I go to the GRUB rescue CLI with the error "out of partition".

I tried to see what's inside the disk `ls (hd0,1)/` and I got the list of directories. If I try to list the content of one of the directories I get an "out of partition" again.

The hardware is actually a virtual machine (QEMU).

Comment: `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/root`, `--boot-directory=/mnt/boot`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging ops, mixed named, just fixed. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: I know grub only. With grub `grub-install` needs a target device (at least I think so and tha man page says so) and produces some really useful messages.

Comment: @HaukeLaging again missing. I forgot to put it on the question... but I did that. Thank you Hauke.

Comment: And the output?

Comment: Tell us more about the hardware's age and setup, please.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I get a success message

Comment: Is that a very old system? It seems that two years ago there was a bug in grub2 causing this.

Comment: Was the system you DD'd from running grub2 without issues? If you list/check your partitions from the live cd, are they still the same sizes you allocated when originally installing?